# SQL - comparing groups to be unique

Tags: sql, sql-server, unique

I am trying to check uniqueness of sets I created in 'group by' clause.

Let's say I have a table called RelevantKeys:

```
KeyID | KeyValue | MainID  
1     | a        |  C1  
1     | a        |  C2  
1     | a        |  C3  
2     | b        |  C1  
2     | b        |  C2  
2     | a        |  C3
```

The KeyIDs with their values form something like a composite key to identify the MainId. I want to check, whether there exist any duplicates.

In the example example above the expected answer is true, because for C1 and C2 have the same KeyValues for all KeyIds:
C1,C2: (a,b)
C4: (a,a)

However, I want a negative answer for the folowing - e.g. if they don't share the whole composition of values, sharing the same value in the first index does not count as duplicate.

```
KeyID | KeyValue | MainID  
1     | a        |  C1  
1     | a        |  C3  
2     | b        |  C1  
2     | a        |  C3
```

It seems logical to group it, but I don't know how to check for uniqueness of all the rows among all the groups. An aggregate function won't work as I need to compare the whole groups, not just the rows inside each.

```
SELECT R.MainID
FROM RelevantKeys R
GROUP BY R.MainID
```

How can I achieve this? Note that the number of KeyIDs is not fixed.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why doesn't the presence of two rows with 1 & a result in a "true" answer in your second example?

Comment: but in the second example does not C1 and C3 share the same value in both keyId and keyValue ?  (i.e.,   {1, a}) ?

Comment: They need to share the whole composition of KeyValues, imagine it as a vector indexed by KeyID with values from the column KeyValue. In the second case the vector for C1 is (a,b) and for C3 it is (a,a), e.g. not same

Comment: Still not clear... What do you mean by "indexing a vector"? Define your terms.  What values are in the vector,? and what operation on that vector are you performing by "indexing" it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use EXCEPT to check for records that exist in one set and not another.  By using two such checks you can make sure that all the records in one group match all the records in another group.  The following lists all the keys and their matches:

```
with mainKeys (MainId) as
(
  select distinct MainId
  from RelevantKeys
)
select k1.MainId as MainId1, k2.MainId as MainId2
from MainKeys k1
cross join MainKeys k2
where k1.MainId != k2.MainId
and not exists
(
  select KeyId, KeyValue
  from RelevantKeys r
  where r.MainId = k1.MainId

  except

  select KeyId, KeyValue
  from RelevantKeys r
  where r.MainId = k2.MainId
)
and not exists
(
  select KeyId, KeyValue
  from RelevantKeys r
  where r.MainId = k2.MainId

  except

  select KeyId, KeyValue
  from RelevantKeys r
  where r.MainId = k1.MainId
)
```

Note that for each match two rows are returned, one for each MainId.  Also, this assumes that the ordering doesn't matter and that no key/value pairs are duplicated within a MainId group.

[Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/aca47/1)

Comment: Awesome, but is it necessary to do it both ways?

Comment: @n1nde If you only do it one way it will match when one MainId's key/value group has all the same key/values plus some extras.  So if C1 had (a,b,c) and C2 had (a,b) it would return a row showing C2 matches C1 but not one showing C1 matched C2.

Comment: Just for a record, in my case I can also assume, that the groups have the same length, e.g. I can check the set difference only once.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
Select keyId, keyvalue, count(distinct mainID)
from RelevantKeys
group by keyId, keyvalue
Having count(distinct mainId) > 1
```

Comment: I'm afraid this does not work in this case - I need to compare the whole composition of KeyValues associated with each MainID, not the combination of KeyID and KeyValue

Comment: Explain what you mean by "the whole composition of key values".  I'm afraid that is still not entirely clear.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I have a group of KeyIDs and each of them has its value. The combination of key and value does not have to be unique, but there cannot be two MainIDs with all the keys with the same value.

Comment: Consider this, let's say that MainID identifies two clients C1 and C2. They have two KeyIDs, for example DatabaseName and ServerName. They can have the same database on different server, they can be on the same server but not the same database.